# Text placement incorrect in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I've got a page that is displaying correctly in Chrome and IE, but not in Firefox.

The File Size and Price are shown below the Download and Buy buttons respectively, except in Firefox where the float up above, lost in the logo: http://playcademy.com/gamepage.php?id=1

I've searched for an answer, and the only thing I've seen is recommendations that I use *{margin:0;padding:0;} in the CSS, but I am already doing that.

I'm betting I'm missing something simple, but my head is ringing from bashing it against this wall. Any insight?

Thanks,
Doug

I can't answer this yet, so I'll just update with what I found- Looks like I was experiencing this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63895. Changing the relatively positioned div above it to display: block from display: table-cell solved it.

Comment: Tested fine for me on Firefox 21, Firefox 22, Chrome, Safari, IE10.

Comment: Tests OK here too in Firefox. Price/File Size are both below the buttons.

Comment: It's fine for me also in FF17, FF21, Chrome.

Comment: @dspaulding "Changing the relatively positioned div above it to display: block from display: table-cell solved it." is this your answer?